# Check whether only one column is NaN from multiple columns, then assign 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check for the following dataframe whether multiple values are empty and then based on that condition assign a 0 to the document type column:

```
    Document Type                          Totaal  Factuurdatum
--  -----------------------------------  --------  --------------
 0  0                                         nan     nan
21  IngramMicro.AccountsPayable.Invoice    562.65  2021-03-16
```

I'm using the following working code for one column:

```
df.loc[df['Totaal'] == 'NaN', 'Document Type'] = 0
```

However, can not make it work to check if ONE column of a list of columns is nan and then assign a 0 .. So which results in more often assigning a 0.

Desired output:

```
    Document Type                          Totaal  Factuurdatum
--  -----------------------------------  --------  --------------
 0  0                                         nan     nan
21  0                                       562.65    nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one value matching by list of columns or [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values match:

```
cols = ['Totaal','Factuurdatum']
df.loc[(df[cols] == 'NaN').any(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0

#laternative for test NaN and nan strings
df.loc[(df[cols].isin(['NaN', 'nan']).any(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0
```

If NaNs are missing values:

```
cols = ['Totaal','Factuurdatum']
df.loc[df[cols].isna().any(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - Sorry I think I framed my question wrongly, how to check whether they are all NaN? 
I've tried the following:

Comment: cols = ['Totaal','Factuurdatum']
df.loc[df[cols].isna().all(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0
However wouldn't work

Comment: @Max - Can you try `df.loc[(df[cols].isin(['NaN', 'nan']).all(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0` ?

Comment: @Max - So need at least one? with any? or all ?

Comment: @Max - Ok, added `any` to answer.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, you've been of great help!

Comment: @Max - so what is correct answer? Now i am confused

Comment: If one column is nan, then 0
cols = ['Totaal','Factuurnummer','IBAN', 'BIC', 'Email', 'BTW', 'ExclBTW', 'Vervaldatum']
df.loc[df[cols].isna().all(axis=1), 'Document Type'] = 0